# Timing of the 2nd Beit Hamikdash's building

Tags: history, historical-figures, beis-hamikdash

If you associate Koresh with Cyrus, Daryavesh with Darius (Cyrus's son) and Artachshasta with Xerxes, there seems to be a 166 year discrepancy between the historical time and the 420 years the Seder Olam Rabbah cites. How is this discrepancy resolved?

Comment: "According to associating..." doesn't parse for me. Do you mean something like "If one associates..."? And anything you can [edit] in as support for your claim that there's an apparent discrepancy would improve your question.

Comment: Rabbi Shimon Schwab in one of his Sefarim discusses at length this discrepancy. I do not remember which one or where.

Comment: The problem is there's not really any sources other than the Seder Olam Rabbah. I'm working on a hypothesis that Artachshasta was Artaxerxes II and that the decree for the return by Cyrus and the actual building were over 100 years apart.

Comment: More importantly, though, are there any sources that the return and the reconstruction must have occurred one right after another and that there could not be a large gap of over 100 years instead of the commonly cited 16 year gap?
To rephrase: Could there have been a large gap between Zerubavel's return and Ezra's return?

Comment: This question is a very poorly posed one for our site, so -1. That doesn't mean what you are trying to discuss isn't important.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30509/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35457/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17223/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25984/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34241/759

Comment: You're working with the hypotheses you mention in your comment ("that Artachshasta... apart") but have no source for them? They were just arbitrary guesses, or what? And you don't cite to the _Seder Olam_, either.

Comment: @msh210 That's a hypothesis only to resolve the discrepancy- don't worry about that. Everything else is going on just various scattered modern opinions instead of concrete Talmudic sources.